# HBase FavoredNodeLoadBalancer won't assign regions to some regionservers

Tags: hadoop, hbase, load-balancing

I recently did an upgrade of HBase to 1.2.6 (running on Hadoop 2.8.3) and switched to using the [FavoredNodeLoadBalancer](https://hbase.apache.org/1.2/devapidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/master/balancer/FavoredNodeLoadBalancer.html). However, when I restarted my master servers, one of my regionservers was down and when the favored nodes were decided for regions, it didn't take into account the regionserver that was down.

Now this regionserver **never** gets assigned any regions and restarting it doesn't help. I also added a brand new regionserver and this also never gets assigned any regions.

I've tried restarting masters, running the balancer, switching to the default balancer (which evenly balances to **ALL** regionservers) and switching back (which returns everything right back to the way it was) and it just won't recalculate that favoured nodes data. It seems like adding a new regionserver is a pretty common use case, am I missing something obvious?

HDFS has block pinning enabled:

```
 <property>
  <name>dfs.datanode.block-pinning.enabled</name>
  <value>true</value>
 </property>
```

Does anyone have any idea how to deal with this? Thanks.